# JavaScript Recursive Function Call Overwrite

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

I have a function:

```
function brackets(openStock, closeStock, s) {
  if (openStock == 0 && closeStock == 0) {
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = s;
  }

  if (openStock > 0) {
     brackets(openStock - 1, closeStock + 1, s + "(");
  }
  if (closeStock > 0) {
     brackets(openStock, closeStock - 1, s + ")");
  }
}
```

It should write the combinations of parenthesizes into a paragraph 'demo' however after writing the first one, the other ones are not written into the paragraph.Since it is a recursive function I don't know how to concatenate the results ( combinations) one after another.

Comment: have you tried wrapping a loop around it?

Comment: It is recursive each function inside the function writes a result

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Also you should use `if...else if`. Using multiple `if`s will overwrote initial value if first condition is true

Comment: then provide us more details, show us the brackets function and your html

Comment: @Unlockedluca The brackets function is already there (but the HTML and the calling code are missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function brackets(openStock, closeStock,s) 
{
    if (openStock == 0 && closeStock == 0) {
       var e = document.createElement('div');
       e.innerHTML = s;

       while(e.firstChild) {
          document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(e.firstChild);
       }
    }

    if (openStock > 0) {
        brackets(openStock-1, closeStock+1, s + "(");
    }
    if (closeStock > 0) {
        brackets(openStock, closeStock-1, s + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please upvote and mark this as correct answer @user7393941

Comment: I have just signed up to the site so it seems I cant upvote but this worked.I don't know why somebody down voted it...

Comment: THAT OK. If possible mark as right answer otherwise enjoy :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume whoever did was concerned that the answer doesn't include any explanation at all. Why didn't the OP's code work?